# How do you keep the every kth element of a list in Ramda?

Tags: ramda.js

How do you filter out every kth element of a list with Ramda?

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

output = keepKth(input, 3)

output = [1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work:

```
  let k = 3;
  let Kth = (value, index) => (index % k == 0)
  let filterKth = R.addIndex(R.filter)(Kth);

  let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  let output = filterKth(input);
```

Comment: That works fine.  Another option would be `compose (map (head), splitEvery (k))`

Answer (score 1):

A variation based on Scott's comment:

```js
const keepEvery = k => compose(pluck(0), splitEvery(k));

keepEvery(3)([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
//=> [1, 4, 7]
```

- https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck
- https://ramdajs.com/docs/#splitEvery

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest, but point free.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const whitelist = R.addIndex(R.reject)(R.flip(R.modulo(R.__, 3)));

console.log(
  whitelist(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.2/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-MEPRnhl9ArIiZuk6ikVrLzYxQm8ov1Ngkn4kIUO82hwpD7d+cwXQ7+isupqVgZ6HHtAEBDMff8eUhzixwEBSbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is another method based on `R.unfold`. The seed is the index (initial 0), and it's incremented by `k` on every iteration.

```js
const { curry, unfold } = R

const fn = curry((k, arr) => unfold(n => n < arr.length && [arr[n], n + k], 0))

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

const result = fn(3, data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.2/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-MEPRnhl9ArIiZuk6ikVrLzYxQm8ov1Ngkn4kIUO82hwpD7d+cwXQ7+isupqVgZ6HHtAEBDMff8eUhzixwEBSbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```